# Stored procedure while loop waiting for output status of another stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, output, wait

I have a small app that records some basic data.

On hitting the save button, the app writes the data to a table using a stored procedure `proc_save`. Within `proc_save`, there is a call to another procedure `proc_sql_job` that runs a SQL Server job.

`proc_sql_job` has an output parameter. It returns either a 1 for completed, 2 for running or 3 for error.

I am OK with capturing the output of `proc_sql_job` inside of `proc_save`.

What I want to do is wait for the `proc_sql_job` to return 1 (or 3 if error) and then proceed with the rest of `proc_save`. How do I do this please? Can I use a `WHILE` LOOP here somehow?

How do I say in SQL to wait and do nothing until the output param from the `proc_sql_job = 1` ?

Comment: Seriously, don't do it. SQL Server is not the place to be putting a wait loop. Instead run a polling service which runs the second half of your SP once it spots that the job has completed. You will have issues for the rest of the product life if you do it as you suggest.

Comment: But its your job :) the command you are looking for is [waitfor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/waitfor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Do you mean like this https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2167/custom-spstartjob-to-delay-next-task-until-sql-agent-job-has-completed/ ?

Comment: Agree with dale.. Might it be better to modify proc_sql_job so that it can accept instruction of what to do next (like a callback in any other context)?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input.. I will re think my approach on this. Cheers